# return not breaking loop (c#)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to determine if a user is a member of a group or not in AD.  However, the following doesn't seem to be working for some reason...

```
public bool MemberOf(string sObjectName, string sGroup, bool bIsGroup)
{
    DirectoryEntry dEntry = CreateDirectoryEntry();
    DirectorySearcher dSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry);
    if (bIsGroup) dSearcher.Filter = "(distinguishedName=" + sObjectName + ")";
    else dSearcher.Filter = "(&(sAMAccountName=" + sObjectName + ")(objectClass=user))";  
    SearchResult sResult = dSearcher.FindOne();
    if (sResult != null)
    {
        foreach (object oGroup in sResult.Properties["MemberOf"])
        {
            if (oGroup.ToString() == sGroup) return true;
            else this.MemberOf(oGroup.ToString(), sGroup, true);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Another variation: http://users.business.uconn.edu/dwick/work/wtf/6-14-2010%201-15-15%20PM.png

Doesn't work either.  This seems like a really dumb question... but shouldn't it break the loop upon "return true;"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's strange that you're calling `this.MemberOf` recursively but ignoring the result of it. Perhaps you meant this:

```
if (oGroup.ToString() == sGroup)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    bool isMember = this.MemberOf(oGroup.ToString(), sGroup, true);
    if (isMember) { return true; }
}
```

The reason why your return statment might appear not to exit the loop is because when you call recursively you have loops inside loops inside loops. Check your call stack - you should notice that `MemberOf` appears multiple time and when you return one of them disappears. By making the above change it will return correctly, unwinding the stack.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that line is executing? Maybe the `if` condition never evaluates to `true`. Place a breakpoint and check. ... and yes, it should break the loop.

Comment: It's also worth noting that string comparisons are case-sensitive by default.

Comment: Putting the return on a separate line will enable you to do this AND make the code more readable.

E.g. if (condition) newline {newline statement newline} newline else newline {newline statement newline} newline

Comment: @Danny, you don't need the return on a different line to set the break point.  Just click on return and hit F9 (assuming you have standard C# bindings)

Comment: I'd place the breakpoint on `if` itself and then manually step into/over the code (since it's pretty clear that it won't ever hit the `return` statement).

Comment: @Matthew, good point, but it will still be easier to read and to set break points the traditional way (clicking on the side) if he uses coding conventions.

Comment: It would probably make the real bug pronounced.  And I would probably do the same as Mehrdad said above.  Heck, I'd probably step the loop and then smack myself for having the recursive call not return.

Answer (score 1):

On this line `this.MemberOf(oGroup.ToString(), sGroup, true);`, don't you want that to actually be `return this.MemberOf(oGroup.ToString(), sGroup, true);`?  You're calling the same function recursively, and no matter if the function evaluates to true or false inside that recursive loop, the function would always return false.

Comment: there can be multiple layers of nesting, so you don't just want to return it immediately

Answer (score 1):

A `return` does indeed exit the loop (except for some edge-cases involving anon-methods!). But I'm more worried about the `else`:

```
else this.MemberOf(oGroup.ToString(), sGroup, true);
```

did you mean to do something more like:

```
else if (this.MemberOf(oGroup.ToString(), sGroup, true)) return true;
```

?

Note; if so you could tidy this to:

```
if (oGroup.ToString() == sGroup ||
      this.MemberOf(oGroup.ToString(), sGroup, true)) {
    return true;
}
```